# Why does GCC emit a repeated `ret`?

Tags: c++, gcc, x86, clang

In the C++ example below, I define a function that computes the height of the leftmost path of a tree.

```cpp
struct TreeNode {
  int value{};
  TreeNode *l = nullptr;
  TreeNode *r = nullptr;
};

int getLeftHeight(TreeNode *root) {
  int height = 0;
  while (root != nullptr) {
    root = root->l;
    height++;
  }
  return height;
}
```

When compiling with GCC 9.3 or 10.1 (using -O3), I get the following x86.

```
getLeftHeight(TreeNode*):
        xor     eax, eax
        test    rdi, rdi
        je      .L4
.L3:
        mov     rdi, QWORD PTR [rdi+8]
        add     eax, 1
        test    rdi, rdi
        jne     .L3
        ret
.L4:
        ret
```

However, when compiling using Clang 10, as shown below, there is not a repeated `ret`.

```
getLeftHeight(TreeNode*):
        xor     eax, eax
        test    rdi, rdi
        je      .LBB0_3
.LBB0_1:
        mov     rdi, qword ptr [rdi + 8]
        add     eax, 1
        test    rdi, rdi
        jne     .LBB0_1
.LBB0_3:
        ret
```

Why is GCC doing this?

As far as I understand, the `ret` will take one extra byte to be encoded.
Maybe this doesn't matter in this case because of alignment/padding of the emitted machine code, but if this is not the case and this duplication happens all over the place in a large codebase, many bytes of machine code could end up being just duplicate `ret`s.

This particular case of duplication also seems fairly simple to spot and optimize away.

Comment: As an aside, what if the deepest path isn't leftmost all the way down? Your approach only works for a _perfectly_ balanced tree along all paths.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings The function is called `getLeftHeight` (rather than `getHeight`) because its purpose is to explicitly return the height by going left as far as possible. However, I now see that in the first sentence I wrote just "computes the height of a tree", which may have caused some confusion.

Comment: Oh yeah, I didn't read the function name :D

Answer (score 6):

This seems to be a missed optimization in GCC.

There is a bug [#71923](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=71923) with a very similar example tagged "missed-optimization".

Having said that, the impact on performance is marginal - mainly on code size. In addition, when the second `ret` is aligned (which will often be the case with modern x86 targets), eliminating the first `ret` would often have no impact on code size, but if eliminated, falling through from the loop would incur decoding the additional `nop` instruction before `ret`, which can make that code path slower.

Anyway, a pull request to GCC is always welcome. You can see the list of optimization passes with `-fdump-passes` and dump the RTL/GIMPLE tree using `-fdump-tree-...` flags (or see it on [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/BDqUhV)). The main question is if an existing optimization pass is supposed to take care of this or if a new one needs to be added (I'm not an expert on GCC, so can't advise one way or another).

Comment: `ret` is 1 byte, it wouldn't be useful to align the jump target in that case.  Even if the `ret` is the last byte in a 16-byte aligned fetch-block, that's totally fine because it's an unconditional jump anyway; bytes after the `ret` have no value to the front-end, so no need to align the ret to let them be fetched more easily along with the `ret`.  (But GCC would have to know about that special case when it should skip `.p2align`, if it normally does align non-loop branch targets.  Fixing this could easily lead to a new missed optimization of inserting a NOP there.)